# Jumping to external url from gridview template field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to jump from existing location to some other location. Like if my application is running on localhost, and i want to jump to Youtube.
Scenario:

I have a grid in which template field is asp:hyperlink. I need to add a image and on on that image click, i will get moved to youtube.

```
<a id="Download" href='<%#ResolveUrl(Eval("Path").ToString()) %>' 
    title="Download>>" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 9pt">
<img src="~/images/dl.gif" style="border:0px; height:22px; width:22px" 
    alt="Download"  runat="server"/></a> 
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# ResolveUrl(Eval("YouTubeUrl").ToString()) %>'>
<img src="~/images/yt.gif" style="border:0px; height:22px; width:22px" 
    alt="Play on You tube" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>
```

I want to navigate some other location outside the current location from the current location.

Comment: it gives url something like that http://localhost/abc.aspx/www.youtube.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<a id="Download" href='<%#ResolveUrl(Eval("Path").ToString()) %>' 
    title="Download>>" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 9pt">
<img src="~/images/dl.gif" style="border:0px; height:22px; width:22px" 
    alt="Download"  runat="server"/></a> 
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("YouTubeUrl").ToString().Contains("http://")?Eval("YouTubeUrl"):"http://"+Eval("YouTubeUrl").ToString() %>'>
<img src="~/images/yt.gif" style="border:0px; height:22px; width:22px" 
    alt="Play on You tube" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("http://{0}", Eval("YouTubeUrl").ToString()) %>'>
```

If this ends up with two http:// at the start then change it to this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("YouTubeUrl").ToString() %>'>
```

Its not clear from what you've posted if the ResolveUrl call is breaking it or if your YouTube url contains the protocol at the start.